# How to get a certificate for a program?

Tags: delphi, antivirus, virus

i created a program using Delphi XE 6 and it's already somehow working.

But there is a big issue. The problem is that almost every anti-virus tool is detecting a virus.
This may be cause by the fact that this program can download files, accesses various websites and it also contains an internal chrome browser.

But is there a way to let the anti-virus tool know that it's not a virus?
Something like a certificate or an official test?

[Source](https://github.com/CreativeMD/CMDLauncher) | [Download](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1265565-cmdlauncher-v2-4-0-install-mods-on-client-server)

Comment: You can just buy a certificate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan He asks for "Something like a certificate", so he is not sure what to do. I personally don't know if an AntiVirus program will act differently, if a known virus signature is found in a file which has a valid AuthentiCode signature. It is probably different for each AntiVirus program if they auto-whitelist programs which have a valid code signature.

Comment: @Daniel The question title is clear

Comment: but @DanielMarschall is right, i have no clue how these things work, it was just a good guess that may something like a certificate exits :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) You can try CodeSigning with AuthentiCode. This has several advantages; for example everybody can verify that the EXE file was created by you, and not modified since then. Also, some AntiVirus programs might accept your EXE if it is signed.

Since you showed us your source code, you probably develop OpenSource. In this case, you can buy an [OpenSource AuthentiCode certificate from Certum](http://www.certum.eu/certum/cert,offer_en_open_source_cs.xml), which is only costing 14 EUR (approx. 17 USD) which is very cheap (a few years ago, they were even free of charge). These certificates have the same security as the very expensive certificates of the competitors ([see price comparison](https://www.sslshopper.com/microsoft-authenticode-certificates.html)), but you may ONLY use the Certum certificate if you use them for signing OpenSource projects.

(2) But first of all, you should try to find out why the AntiVirus program detects your program as malicious. Please try uploading it to virustotal.com and find out if other AntiVirus programs act the same way. There is a chance that a part of your program looks "similar" to a known virus. In this case, you would have to contact your AntiVirus company and report a false-positive.

Comment: Thanks for this quick and good response :D i will try to sign my Application this may fix some problems.